# How port names are resolved in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

There's a working k8s configuration which uses the same port name in a pod and in a service. Here's a config part of the pod:

```
ports:
- containerPort: 8000
  name: app-port
  protocol: TCP
```

Here's a config part of the service:

```
  ports:
  - name: app-port
    nodePort: 32000
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: app-port
  type: NodePort
```

How is the name `app-port` resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the Service, it is associated with Pods selected by the label selector defined in the Service `spec.selector`.

When a request is made to the Service, the Control Plane retrieves its `spec.ports[*].targetPort` value:

- If it does not exist, the value of `spec.ports[*].port` field is used instead to forward traffic to the Pods.
- If it does exist and it is a number, the `targetPort` value is used to forward traffic to the Pods.
- If it is a string, the Control Plane looks up the port by name in `spec.ports[*].name` of the Pod, and uses the port with the matching name as the target port.

Here is the relevant piece of code in Kubernetes:

```golang
// FindPort locates the container port for the given pod and portName.  If the
// targetPort is a number, use that.  If the targetPort is a string, look that
// string up in all named ports in all containers in the target pod.  If no
// match is found, fail.
func FindPort(pod *v1.Pod, svcPort *v1.ServicePort) (int, error) {
    portName := svcPort.TargetPort
    switch portName.Type {
    case intstr.String:
        name := portName.StrVal
        for _, container := range pod.Spec.Containers {
            for _, port := range container.Ports {
                if port.Name == name && port.Protocol == svcPort.Protocol {
                    return int(port.ContainerPort), nil
                }
            }
        }
    case intstr.Int:
        return portName.IntValue(), nil
    }
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("no suitable port for manifest: %s", pod.UID)
}
```

[source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.26.0/pkg/api/v1/pod/util.go#L32)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will refer to the target port with the **port number**. But, you can give a name to each port mentioned in the pod configuration and use this name in the **service** to refer to the specified port. By this your **service** will be aware of which port it needs to consider from the pod.

To answer your question, the **port name** which you created in the **pod belongs only to the pod configuration**. It can be used as a reference to get the portnumber of a pod. But in your service you are creating a new **portname** attribute which only belongs to the service. The `targetPort` in service will only consider the port number from the `portname` attribute created in the service and not from the pod.

Likewise the kubernetes knows that it needs to consider the `target port number` for the **service** by the **port name** created in the **service** and not from the **pod**.

Basically k8's uses DNS to determine all this stuff. For more information you can refer to this [link1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) [link2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)